# UITextview Save to Sqlite iOS 9 Not Working

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitextview, ios9

I have an application that uses Sqlite as the db. This app has worked for a few years with no problem. With the release of iOS 9, I cannot save any of the UITextviews to the database. Everything else still saves with no problems. The app returns no error when saving and it looks like everything works, but when I look in the database the fields have null values for any data that is a blob. Does anyone know what the issue is?

This is not much help because this problem is with all my apps now with iOS 9 and UITextview saving. Here's a snippet of code:

```
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &BratAppsDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char* sqliteQuery = "UPDATE MyDatabase SET TheTextView=? Where ID='1'";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(BratAppsDB, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [TheUITextView.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            sqlite3_step(statement);
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(BratAppsDB));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(MyDB);
    }
```

Comment: No one can help if you don't post relevant code in your question.

Comment: Check the return value of sqlite_bind_blob and sqlite_step. And why are you storing a string with sqlite3_bind_blob instead of sqlite3_bind_text?

Comment: How do you check the return value of the sqlite3_bind_blob?  The UITextview can hold large amounts of data. My one app can have multiple pages that need to be saved, and to my understanding the sqlite3_bind_text does not hold as much data. I have done it this way for years until now. Maybe they did change something in SQLite framework.  Because they big mess it up in Xcode 7 that you have to add the framework manually now.

Comment: Yup - The problem is with the Blob. Seem Apple changed something.

Comment: Submitted bug report to Apple.

Comment: BTW - I make extensive use of sqlite in an app. I have a `TEXT` column in a table and I have no problem storing large amounts of text using `sqlite3_bind_text`. It's been working since iOS 3.0 and it still works (in the most recent update) under iOS 9. Try it. No need to use `BLOB` to store text. Never has been either.

Comment: Thanks Maddy - That was my change to a Text not a blob. Question: What about storing of images? I was storing images from the user's camera in the database and I am am pretty sure that has to be a blob. Those are not saving as well. Not sure how to save those now, other than link to them in the users Photo Album. This is going to be a big re-write again. Also, just tried the most recent iOS9 and still you cannot save anything to a blob. Also, did you notice that they removed the libsqlite3.dylib framework? You have to manually add it now in Xcode 7.

Comment: I have several `BLOB` columns that I store little bits of data in. Nothing as large as image data so I can't speak to why saving image data into a `BLOB` column isn't working. My long standing Xcode project continues to function as-is after going from Xcode 6 to Xcode 7. I've always linked `libsqlite3.dylib` in my project and it has always worked just fine - even now with Xcode 7 and iOS 9. Can't speak to a new project created with Xcode 7.

Comment: Thanks Maddy Have you confirmed that your current app is saving the data to a blob using iOS9? I have to re-write all of my apps, try to find another way to save blob data. I even turned the sell of several off until I can get to them. I have reported this to Apple - Bug Report. It does seem that others are having the same issue. Also, if you load your project that was linked to libsqlite3.dylib in Xcode 6 in Xcode 7 you will see that the reference to the libsqlite3.dylib is red, and that is because it's missing. It will still work just don't delete it, or you will have to link it manually.

Comment: Yes, I have no problems at all saving small amounts of data to a `BLOB` column under iOS 9. As I said, I don't save large blobs, just little ones (less than 20 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "-1", put the length:

sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [TheUITextView.text UTF8String], **(int)TheUITextView.text.length**, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

JP

Comment: I'll try that and see what happens. Thanks!